# My call on function wont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi :) I'm trying to make a quiz, the thing is it works when i use the on() method as it is shown in the commented line other than that it doesn't, I'm confused.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // $('input[name="q1--r1"]').on('click', function () {
        function checkAnswer(e) {

            var answers = $('input[name=e]'); 

            for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
                if(answers[i].checked){
                    if(answers[i].value === 'correct'){
                        alert('corrrrrrrrrect');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        $('input[name="q1--r1"]').on('click', checkAnswer(q1--r1));
        $('input[name="q1--r1"]').on('click', checkAnswer(q2--r2));
        $('input[name="q1--r1"]').on('click', checkAnswer(q3--r3));
        //});

}
```

```html
<h2>Just Take This Quiz : </h2>
<div class="quiz">

    <div class="q1">
        <p class="q1-question">9 x 2 is </p>
        <span><input type="radio" name="q1--r1" value="wrong">19</span><br>
        <span><input type="radio" name="q1--r1" value="wrong">17</span><br>
        <span><input type="radio" name="q1--r1" value="correct">18</span><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve, and how you expect the quiz to behave?

Comment: `$(".quiz radio").click(function () {  if (this.checked && this.value == "correct") alert("correct"); }); ` should be all the js you need.